# Arrays and Rvalues (as parameters)

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11, rvalue-reference, rvalue

I wonder if there is any way to differentiate the function calls (with arrays as parameters) shown in the following code:

```
#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>

template <size_t Size>
void foo_array( const char (&data)[Size] )
{
    std::cout << "named\n";
}

template <size_t Size>
void foo_array( char (&&data)[Size] )  //rvalue of arrays?
{
    std::cout << "temporary\n";
}


struct A {};

void foo( const A& a )
{
    std::cout << "named\n";
}

void foo( A&& a )
{
    std::cout << "temporary\n";
}


int main( /* int argc, char* argv[] */ )
{
    A a;
    const A a2;

    foo(a);
    foo(A());               //Temporary -> OK!
    foo(a2);

    //------------------------------------------------------------

    char arr[] = "hello";
    const char arr2[] = "hello";

    foo_array(arr);
    foo_array("hello");     //How I can differentiate this?
    foo_array(arr2);

    return 0;
}
```

The foo "function family" is able to distinguish a temporary object from a named. Is not the case of foo_array.

Is it possible in C++11 ?
If not, do you think could be possible? (obviously changing the standard)

Regards.
Fernando.

Comment: If you used `std::array<>` instead of raw C-arrays, this would be trivial.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with `foo_array`. It's the test case that is bad: `"hello"` is an lvalue! Think about it. It is not a temporary: string literals have static storage duration.

An array rvalue would be something like this:

```
template <typename T>
using alias = T;
// you need this thing because char[23]{} is not valid...

foo_array(alias<char[23]> {});
```

Comment: Here's a similar example (downgraded to fit GCC 4.5 limited C++11 support) on ideone: http://ideone.com/lgItR

Comment: Very nice. Can a temporary array decay to a pointer? I.e. is it something that actually has an address?

Comment: @KerrekSB interesting question that I'm afraid I don't know the answer to (and I do't have time for much research right now). May be worth posting a new question about it.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes Thanks!
You are right. I was confused.
The question is meaningless.
Nice trick!

Comment: @KerrekSB Yes, it can decay. However the address is that of the first element, not of the temporary itself. It is already possible to access subobject of a temporary in other fashions (e.g. `foo {}.bar` -- note that you can't take *that* address though, this is a prvalue).

Comment: Please take a look at this question(have a discussion on the two ways: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50679635/type-aliascharn-vs-charn-in-functions-argument

Comment: @KerrekSB for `alias<char[23]`, gcc and clang treats it differently(gcc `error: taking address of temporary array` whereas clang compile happily) look at the thread I posted above, which have demos.

Comment: @陳力: Works in both GCC and Clang for me (e.g. https://wandbox.org/permlink/xZfOinNTDtjLVau9). Note that we're not taking addresses, we're binding to a const lvalue ref (which is something prvalues can do).