# Is reinterpret_cast to C-style array illegal C++11?

Tags: c++, casting, reinterpret-cast, arrays

Why is the following code frowned upon?

```
double d[4] = {0,1,2,3};
reinterpret_cast<double[2]>(d);
```

GCC declares it an `invalid cast from type 'double*' to type 'double [2]'` and clang declares that `reinterpret_cast from 'double *' to 'double [2]' is not allowed`

Now in case the intent is not obvious, I would like this code to return a double[2] that contains {0,1}, pretty much like a `reinterpret_cast<double*>(d)` would. (Hence I know it would work with pointers, so that's not what I'm asking)

Comment: No expression can yield an array in C or C++ -- arrays cannot be rvalues. They always have a name and an address.

Comment: @JohannesD is a string literal an expression? :P

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes Damn, you got me there :P Also, there are array literals in C99... Oh well. Perhaps the correct thing to say is that there cannot be *temporary* array objects at runtime. String literals (and presumably the C99 array literals) are still lvalues, not rvalues.

Comment: @JohannesD `using type = int[]; type{1, 2, 3, 4, 5};` <-- temporary array.

Comment: @JohannesD haha! Gotcha there as well (man, C++ is messed up) http://stackoverflow.com/a/10624677/46642

Comment: Anonymous downvoter: please enlighten me as to why you consider my genuine question a bad one.

Comment: @JohannesD: So what is Jarod42's answer then? I'm puzzled

Comment: @GurgHackpof a reference to a supposed array of two elements. You should notice that no such array exists, temporary or not. (If it's not clear, what I mean is "don't do that")

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both compilers are correct.

`reinterpret_cast` is not a hammer, it's a powerful precision tool. All uses of `reinterpret_cast` have to involve at least one pointer or reference type as the source or as the destination, except for the degenerate case of an identity integral conversion (i.e. `reinterpret_cast` from `int` to `int` is allowed and does nothing.)

Answer (score 9):

What you may want is

```
double (&d2)[2] = reinterpret_cast<double(&)[2]>(d);
```

Not sure it is not pedantically undefined behavior though (as most usage of `reinterpret_cast`).

Comment: ok please enlighten me as to what this thing actually means. 
It seems to be working with GCC [(example)](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=0de88e758516912c699e7c1993b30cbd-1dfe2a0b480865877d574c97e8ac73e5), but clang warns that it is undefined-reinterpret-cast `error: reinterpret_cast from 'double [4]' to 'double (&)[2]' has undefined behavior [-Werror,-Wundefined-reinterpret-cast]`

Comment: @GurgHackpof if the compiler says it's a terrible idea it probably is :)

Comment: `double (&d2)[2] = *reinterpret_cast<double(*)[2]>(d);` isn't UB, as fair as I know. This "trick" can be used as a small window into a larger array, eg. when using ranged-for: `char str[5]{...}; for(char c : *reinterpret_cast<char(*)[4]>(str)) {...`.

Answer (score 1):

You have an array (not a pointer) of size 4. You cannot cast it to an array of size 2 because of the simple fact that the size is incorrect. A similar example is that you couldn't cast an instance of a class to an instance of a class to an instance of another class, because that just doesn't make any sense. To get an array with `{0,1}` you have to make a whole new array.

Here's the right way to do it:

```
     double d[4] = {0,1,2,3};                                                    
     double copy[2]{};                                                           
     std::copy_n(std::begin(d),2,std::begin(copy));
```

If you don't want to create a copy of the array the idiomatic thing to do is operate on a  range instead of an array, there is a reason every algorithm in the standard lib operates on iterators not containers.

Comment: Well I'm trying to alias a subset of my array. Not copying it is the whole point.

Comment: @GurgHackpof that's the whole reason C++ uses iterators for all of it's algorithms, operate on a range, don't try to do anything tricky