# Is type punning arrays of same type but different size allowed?

Tags: c++, arrays, language-lawyer, type-punning

Is type punning arrays of the same type but with a different size still a violation of strict aliasing?

```
int arr[4];
int(&ref)[2] = reinterpret_cast<int(&)[2]>(arr);

arr[0] = 0; //write to original
ref[0]; //read from pun
```

Comment: Related to [is-reinterpret-cast-to-c-style-array-illegal-c11](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18514490/is-reinterpret-cast-to-c-style-array-illegal-c11).

Answer (score 1):

We can argue as follows; [[expr.reinterpret.cast]/11](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.reinterpret.cast#11):

> A glvalue expression of type `T1` can be cast to the type “reference
>   to `T2`” if an expression of type “pointer to `T1`” can be explicitly
>   converted to the type “pointer to `T2`” using a `reinterpret_cast`.
>   **The result refers to the same object as the source glvalue, but with the specified type.**

[[conv.array]](http://eel.is/c++draft/conv.array):

> An lvalue or rvalue of type “array of `N T`” […] can be converted to a
>   prvalue of type “pointer to `T`”. **The result is a pointer to the
>   first element of the array.**

I.e. arguably, we have a pointer that *points* to (not just merely represents the address of) the first element. And it is of that element's type. Thus accessing `ref[0]` should be defined.

By this logic, it is also  fine to write

```
auto& ref = reinterpret_cast<unsigned(&)[200]>(arr);
std::cout << ref[0];
```