# `type_alias<char[N]>{}` VS `char[N]{}` in function's argument

Tags: c++, gcc, arguments, clang, language-lawyer

- Environment: x86-64 **Clang** 6.0.0

function's definition:

```
void foo(const char*) {}
```

1. `foo(char[16]{}); //houston, there is a problem!`
2. `foo(type_alias<char[16]>{}); //compile happily`

`type_alias` is simple:

```
template<typename T>
using type_alias = T;
```

[**`live demon`**](https://godbolt.org/g/6MmABg)

---

As comment notes, `case 1` cannot compile while `case 2` can.

I know that `alias declarations` with `using` is not text substitution(like `#define`) and it is a synonym for the type.

But I still cannot figure out how to account for this situation. Then I give **GCC** a [**`try`**](https://wandbox.org/permlink/RKLfaLiEU4HnW6HS):

```
prog.cc: In function 'int main()':
prog.cc:11:7: error: expected primary-expression before 'char'
   foo(char[16]{});
       ^~~~
prog.cc:12:7: error: taking address of temporary array
   foo(type_alias<char[16]>{});
       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Ah, **GCC** gave me an error instead! Then I compile it with different versions of the two compilers:

- **Clang**'s error message for `case 1` is:

> prog.cc:11:11: error: expected '(' for function-style cast or type construction
>
> ```
> foo(char[16]{});
>       ~~~~^
> ```

- **Clang** lets `case 2` pass.
- **GCC**'s forbid both the two cases to pass competition. Error messages for `case 1` and `case 2` have been listed above.

BTW, for **Clang**, I have also tested with `pedantic-errors`, but nothing changed.

---

Questions:

- For `case 2`: **Clang**, **GCC**, who conforms the standard? Any spec in standard(language lawyer)?
- For `case 1`: Whose error message is more correct(IOW, conforms the standard)?

## Update

As VTT comments, for `case 1`, it should be `foo(const char[16]{});`. Apology for this mistake.

But **Clang** can compile `foo(type_alias<char[16]>{});`. It seems to be a bug?

Comment: Shouldn't case 1 be `foo((const char[16]){});`? Aren't extra parentheses required because type name contains more than one token, like in case of `foo((unsigned int){});`?

Comment: @VTT Thanks! My faults.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, `type_alias<cv T>{}` is equivalent to `(cv T){}`, not to `cv T{}`. This distinction matters when `T` is an array:

```
foo((const char[16]){});              // OK
foo(type_alias<const char[16]>{});    // OK

foo(const type_alias<char>[16]{});    // KO
foo(const char[16]{});                // KO
```

Demo: https://wandbox.org/permlink/KGf3HVqN3USq6yy8

---

> For case 2: Clang, GCC, who conforms the standard? Any spec in standard(language lawyer)?

Both does, both accept `foo(type_alias<char>[16]{})`, but gcc *warns* you about it (and since you compiled with `-Werror`, this warning is turned into an error ;).

Comment: How does this explain why `foo(type_alias<char[16]>{})` compiles?

Comment: @Zereges you can implicitly convert a pointer-to-non-const to a pointer-to-const.

Comment: I meant why former compiles, but `foo(char[16]{})` doesn't.

Comment: It seems GCC does give error, not warning, please take a look at(turn off all warnings): https://wandbox.org/permlink/4cHxwKEakCw3DcS6

Comment: @陳力 You're right oO I think it _should_ be a warning. Let me see that.

Comment: @陳力 I don't know. I've found nothing in the Standard making it an error, but it doesn't mean it is not. Hoping someone else find it.